# function cannot return null in c

Tags: c, null, stack

My code is supposed to push a StackNode item into a Stack. However, when the stack is full, I'm trying to get the function to not push anymore, and return a null, but it won't return a null!

```
Stack push(Stack stk,int data)
{
  struct StackNode *top = stk.top;
  struct StackNode *node = malloc(sizeof(struct StackNode));
  if(node == NULL)
  {
    printf("Stack is full\n");
    return NULL;
  }

  node->data = data;
  node->nextNode = top;
  stk.top = node;
  stk.count++;
  return stk;
}
```

Here is the error I'm getting: 
`error: returning 'void *' from a function with incompatible
      result type 'Stack' (aka 'struct Stack')
    return NULL;`

I'm not sure what this means. How do I fix it? What is the NULL equivalent of a Stack?

Comment: What is not clear in the error message? Is `NULL` a value of type `Stack`?

Comment: I don't know what the null equivalent for a Stack is

Comment: There is no equivalent.

Comment: then what can I return when the stack is full?

Comment: Your function and approach have to be redesigned. For example return `bool` instead, which will indicate the success/failure.

Comment: @ashadeka: That's for you to decide. Why are you even trying to pass and return your stack *by value*? This makes no sense at all. You need a complete redesign of your passing (and returning) approach.

Comment: What is "a null"? Hint: Not what you think it is!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there are some basic things you should rethink:
First, only pointers can be `NULL`, but not objects. Hence, if you return an object of type `struct Stack` (which is not a pointer), you cannot return `NULL` but just an instance of `struct Stack`.

Second, passing in and returning an object of `struct Stack` by value will result in copying the respective object; I think that passing references or pointers would be a better choice; and - if you pass in and return a pointer, you could also return `NULL` to indicate a full stack or some other issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your function must return a value that has the type `Stack`.

The code you provided doesn't define the type of `NULL`, but, since you're not seeing another error and you're assigning it to `node`, I would guess that the type of `NULL` is `StackNode *`... or, at least, something compatible with that.

So, there's your problem. You're trying to return something with the type `StackNode *` when your function claims to return a `Stack`.

Your best bet is to redesign this function that returns the result of the `push` operation and not the `Stack` itself.

Comment: _"The code you provided doesn't define the type of NULL, but, since you're not seeing another error and you're assigning it to node, I would guess that the type of NULL is StackNode *... or, at least, something compatible with that."_ NULL is provided by the implementation, and certainly won't be a `StackNode*`. It is often `0`, or `(void*)0`. It is a part of C and of C++.

Comment: Most likely, yes... but `NULL` is only defined as `(void *)0` if you've included a header that defines it as such.

Comment: It is several orders of magnitude more likely that the OP's full code includes that header, than that the OP is trying to create his own `NULL` and failed to actually write said definition or even mention it to us.